# How to share a C# Integer variable with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, variables

I want to share the `currentTab` variable which exists on the C# server side with JavaScript. Here is my code:

**C#:**

```
public int currentTab = 1;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "addScript", "showTab(" + currentTab + ");", true);
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var currentTab = "<%=currentTab%>";

function showTab(index)
{
    currentTab = index;
    // Show tab at (index)
}
```

I used this approach to get the current tab again on PostBack. However, `currentTab` on C# is remains `1` after `PostBack`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the index from your javascript function, to a hiddenfield, and then read that on postback.

In your code, you check the hiddenfield, if your page is postback.
Like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            currentTab = Int32.Parse(HiddenTabValue.Value);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In your Page_Load, you can check if IsPostback is true. If it is true, do your postback logic. Like parsing the value of the hiddenfield, into an int.

Answer (score 2):

Have a server side [hidden field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) to hold this piece of information.

You can access the field through javascript and as a server side control the value will be available server side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some server control to send value back to the server (i.e. `asp:HiddenField`) or use query string to set the tab index there.