# How can I share a variable between my C# ASP.NET code and the HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share a variable between C# and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532592/how-to-share-a-variable-between-c-sharp-and-javascript)

I am enhancing a C# ASP.NET web app that has two important divisions in the HTML. Two menu options are available to cause one to be hidden and the other to be unhidden. Let's call them Page One and Page Two.

The problem is that some things on the page cause a postback, which causes a total refresh and forces the default to be Page One. Also we automatically do a refresh every five minutes to get new page content. If the user happens to be viewing Page Two when the refresh occurs either automatically or because of a postback after the user has clicked on certain things, the page automatically goes back to Page One.

Long term the solution is to properly use AJAX. For now I need a quick and dirty way to remember which page the user is on when a refresh occurs and then put him back on that page upon refresh.

Can I create a variable on the server side in C# that I can interrogate on the client side with JavaScript? Technically the server does not need to know which page div is displayed in the browser if I can somehow make the client remember it from page refresh to refresh. Is there a way to do that?

Forgive me if this seems elementary. I have many years of programming experience (mostly C/C++ in the MS-DOS and Unix worlds), but not very much in the ASP.NET environment.

Comment: You should try to explain your problems to the point , what you want to do instead of this much detail . Its hard figure out what you exactly need .

Comment: Does the server know which page the client is on?  Or does only the javascript know that?

Comment: No, the server does not know which page is displayed. It sends all the HTML for both pages down every time. (Technically it's one page with two different divs, and one is hidden while the other is displayed.) JavaScript on the client side hides one div and shows the other each time one of two links (Page One and Page Two) is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using meta tag to refresh the page `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600"/>`, then you should pass a tab/page id along with the url:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600;url=http://yourdomain.com/page.html?tab=<%= tab %>/">
```

Also add this attribute when you send any postback to the page.

Now, you just need to read a value of this attribute on the server side and replace it in the meta refresh tag:

```
tab = Request.QueryString["tab"]
```

Comment: This seems like an intriguing solution, but what about the details? Does my JavaScript have to do anything? Or does my server-side code have to interrogate the tab value and then send back only the right HTML for the selected page?

Comment: @DaveInATL - It can render the HTML with that tab value already set, by using `<%= %>` tags in your javascript.

Comment: Okay, thanks Bobson. I think I've arrived at a solution using asp:HiddenField in combination with a Session State variable on the server side. I'll try to post more info later.

Comment: @DavelnATL your sulution is probably good too. There is one downside, thought: using session state it's impossible to add a bookmark to the displayed tab. Also, url is not search engine friendly. But that's ok if this is a intranet web app.

Comment: Piotr, yes it is an intranet app. Thanks for the feedback.